# Use serviceworker to switch routes without sending request to server

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, react-router-dom

I Have a `React` application with `react-router-dom`. The static files(`index.html`,`blah blah.js`,...) are served with `Apache server` which reroutes all requests to `index.html` using `.htaccess`.I use `Webpack` to compile all react and babel code to single `.js` file. The whole content is loaded in the first visit(plus `cache first SW` employed).

Each time A route( Eg. `/profile`) is loaded, The request is passed to the server(An HTTP request is sent) causing unnecessary delay 

**How can I switch routes without sending any request to the server?**

**Is it possible to use a `Service Worker`(just like My cache first approach)?**

Here is my react router component

```
class App extends React.Component{
   render(){
       return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/profile" exact component={Profile} />
                    <Route path="/about"  component={About}/>

                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
   }     
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: When you say `/profile` is loaded, what do you mean? Are you hitting the url in the browser? Or are you using client side routing? Can you post some code and add more info to your question?

Comment: What I want is client-side routing without any hashed URL(no `/#!/profile` just `/profile`

Comment: That's not what is asked in the question I suppose. Anyway, `BrowserRouter` will not give you hashed URLs if I'm not wrong.

Comment: true, But I want some kind of mechanism to move through my routes without actually running an HTTP request(As all the required code is downloaded already by the browser). I'm checking whether I can place a service worker in between the navigation and prevent a wasteful HTTP request.

Comment: I don't see a http request being made in the question? When the route is switched, `Profile` component is rendered, that is all. Not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: At that point, the browser goes to the Apache server and redirects the request to index.html (using `.htaccess` RewriteRule ) and then the `Profile` component is rendered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178569/discussion-between-yaswanth-and-anandhu).

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to do is known as the ["Application Shell" architectural pattern](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/app-shell).

The trick is to have your service worker's `fetch` handler check to see whether an incoming request is a [navigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode#Value) (`event.request.mode === 'navigate'`), and if so, respond with the cached App Shell HTML (which sounds like `/index.html` in your case).

A generic way of doing this would be:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
    event.respondWith(caches.match('/index.html'));
  } else {
    // Your other response logic goes here.
  }
});
```

This will cause your service worker to behave in a similar fashion to how you're web server is already configured.

Comment: Thanks, "Application shell" information was very helpful.It looks like my exact problem.